# OSM on Android App

Tags: android, openstreetmap, qgis, mapserver, nativeapplication

I want to use a map, do some editing and display in a native android application.  OSM is the best for these kinds of things as I heard. But I do not have a good knowledge about the technology stack. Could you please tell me which is correct? Or suggest something that suits.

OSM -> QGis -> MapServer -> Android Studio

Comment: There are multiple possible solutions but the easiest one is probably a local OSM database and a mapserver / [tile server](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) which then gets queried from your osmdroid-based app. But this is the wrong place for asking questions about preferred software, better re-ask your question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/ and try to provide a few more requirements for your app.

Comment: thanks il do that :)